# How can I add the data to jquery DataTable as dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, datatable

I use the `DataTable` version 1.10. I want to add dynamically. I know that need to use the `table.push()` method for this. But I don't know how can I use the `table.push()` method. Is there anyone help me in this regard.

I do like this:

```
var body = '<tr>';
body += '<td>' +
  '<div class="img-container">' +
  '<img src="../../assets/img/room-plan/' + r_plan + '" alt="..." id="imgsrc">' +
  '</div>' +
  '</td>';
body += '<td id="imgname">' + r_name + '</td>';
body += '<td class="text-right">' +
  '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-warning btn-icon edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>' +
  '<a href="#" class="btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon remove" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>' +
  '</td>';
body += '</tr>';

$('#datatables').dataTable().fnDestroy();

$(body).appendTo($("tbody"));
// $('#datatables').dataTable();

var table = $('#datatables').DataTable({
  "pagingType": "full_numbers",
  "lengthMenu": [
    [10, 25, 50, -1],
    [10, 25, 50, "All"]
  ],
  responsive: true,
  language: {
    search: "_INPUT_",
    searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
    //"zeroRecords": " "
  }

});

table.push(body);
```

What is the problem in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
  var newRow = "<tr><td>row 3, cell 1</td><td>row 3, cell 2</td></tr>";
  var table = $('table').DataTable();
  table.row.add($(newRow)).draw();
```